# Online edit a file(pg_hba.conf) using ansible and jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible, pg-hba.conf

guys,
I want to use ansible to open a file, for example pg_hba.conf in realtime (like vim) and be able to edit it on the fly.
I want to be able to choose the group of target servers from jenkins, read the contents of pg_hba.conf of a particular node, and pass these contents as parameter, which I can edit in a free form text. After I press a "build" button to save the new changes into the group of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this with ansible modules like copy, template, lineinfile, blockinfile.

I think the best way is using template module but some time lineinfile will be work for you (See [official ansible module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html)).

As current working example for your problem, see [this git repo](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-postgresql/blob/master/tasks/configure.yml#L11).

Let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: I want before the edit to display the contents of the particular pg_hba.conf file

Comment: I didn't get your problem. Could you please describe why do you want to display content of pg_hba.conf!?

Comment: You can use the `slurp` module to retrieve the base64 contents of a file (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/slurp_module.html): "This module works like fetch. It is used for fetching a base64- encoded blob containing the data in a remote file". You can register the results and print the contents on screen with the `debug` module (e.g. check the modules examples).

Comment: Masseyb, thanks for the replay. I've did something similar, instead of slurp, I've used "cat" command in a shell command. With slurp the data is displayed on one row.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
tasks:
    -
      name: cat the pg_file
      shell: cat "{{ pg_path }}"
      register: predata
    - debug:
        msg: "{{predata.stdout_lines|list}}"
```